# one word that can describe lock / unlock

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

I need a word that could be used equally to describe the action of locking or unlocking.

Context is naming a class in a program (code) that would contain both actions of locking and unlocking a record.

My primary language is not English so I cannot think of one or don't know if it exist.

Comment: Words tend not to be coined where there is limited requirement for them.

Comment: Meh, maybe *toggle*? Or *slide the bolt* (which doesn't inherently indicate in which direction).

Comment: `toggle-lock`, `lock-or-unlock`,... This is programming - you can invent your own names. You need not look for existing single English words.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because a programming name is sought, not necessarily an existing English word.

Comment: I'd call it "LockManager", which suggests it's in charge of removing/adding the locked status.

Comment: @danBron - gonna a raise a feature request to automatically convert all your comments to answers man! :P

Comment: @BiscuitBoy I'm going to raise a FR to detect when someone asks me to convert my comments into an answer, automatically reminds them I welcome and encourage them to do so under their own auspices, requiring neither my permission nor even citation of me. ;)

Comment: Secure?  Secure Status?  Lock State?

Comment: So often does this type of question arise, I feel sure someone will one day ask if there is a single word which comprises both *up* and *down*, or *right* and *left*. Only in those cases I suppose one could offer *direction*. But no, I can't think of anything which could mean either *lock* or *unlock*.

Comment: @MaxWilliams can you make an answer with your comment? I decided to take that as my solution

Comment: @DanBron The word *toggle* has **nothing to do with locks or (un)locking**. It applies to switching between any two states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd call it "LockManager", which suggests it's in charge of removing/adding the locked status.

Answer (score 3):

The word you are looking for is [**toggle**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/toggle).

(Toggle lock on or off)

This is a verb that is used within computing to indicate something is alternating between discrete states - I've only ever known it to be used in a binary sense (typically for an on/off switch).

Comment: No. Toggle means to switch between binary states. It has nothing per se to do with locks or locking. A toggle that switches between the two states locked and unlocked is what this question is about.